# how to understand what happens when you duplicate frames

Tags: animation, rigging, game-engine, armature

### how to understand what happens when you duplicate frames

for example I have this animation and select everything in the 3d view, then press copy and then move on the timeline to the place I want to place them and press paste.

- the copied keyframes include the first keyframe that in my walking animation will be the last one
- then paste everything marking the keyframe 40 as a place and
- I suppose that the kyeframe 1 is left over the keyframe 40 and
- I do not understand if it is overlapped or replaced or they will remain as two
  keyframes in the same place on the timeline,
- and I guess this ruins my animation cycle because what
- I want is to lengthen the cycle of walking with fluids and smoothness

then I assume that if I have 40 keyframes starting the copy in keyframe 2 and I must select 30 and paste them in 41 so that the number 40 in the duplicate becomes the number 80

### **How can i solve this problem ???**

[image: Duplicate KeyFrame]

Comment: could you please share your file, at least the armature, so we can try to do what you're trying to do, because right now it's hard to understand...

Comment: what is difficult to understand? the question refers to knowing if I duplicate the frames and paste them next to the ones I have creates a double frame? like when 2 vertices are ensiled and in the same vector and you need to apply the doubles to be just a vertex and eliminate the doubles that are occupying the same vector and join to form a single TRIS